# Text chatting using webrtc and node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, webrtc

I have search on Google but didn't get proper  example how to create Text chat application using webRTC and node.js .

Please if anybody knows how to do this .please share details .

Comment: Please read the stackoverflow FAQ for proper question asking.

Answer (score 6):

Since webRTC uses peer-to-peer communication, you may not need node.js to make the chat.

However, you may use node.js to do the signaling to set up the communication (using Websockets for example).
Once you have the RTCPeerConnection up and running, you can use the RTCDataChannel to send text.

The link below may get you started

http://simpl.info/rtcdatachannel/